# NSPredicate format specifiers issue

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I use this predicate:

```
NSPredicate *offencePredicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ == %@) AND (%@ == %d)", kTeamID, self.selectedTeam.teamID, kPlayerZoneID, ZoneIdTypeOffence];
```

but the predicate is:

```
"teamID" == 10 AND "playerZoneID" == 3
```

instead of:

```
teamID == 10 AND playerZoneID == 3
```

How can I trim this `""` when I use format specifiers for predicating. And the next question is: is this the right solution using form specifiers in predicate. Because I have some API keys that are correspond to my core data entries attributes. So it is ok to use constant string that will allow quite faster changes if I need to change some of these keys, but is it ok to use this constant for predication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `%K` for the keys.

It would look like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K == %@) AND (%K == %d)", kTeamID, self.selectedTeam.teamID, kPlayerZoneID, ZoneIdTypeOffence];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `%K`.

See this example from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795):

```
NSString *attributeName = @"firstName";
NSString *attributeValue = @"Adam";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",
    attributeName, attributeValue];
```

Result:

```
firstName like "Adam"
```